# Find if one string is substr of another using strpos

Tags: php, strpos

I have the following statement to check if `$word_to_compare` is a substring of `$word`.

```
if(strpos($word,$word_to_compare)!==false)
    {
            echo"Match found";
            }
```

The above logic does not return a match for `$word_to_compare = achiev` and 
`$word = achievement`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/83LRSx

Comment: `var_dump($word);` and `var_dump($word_to_compare);`.  Make sure there aren't any hidden characters/whitespace.

Comment: using `trim($word)` and `trim($word_to_compare)` will remove any nasty whitespace that could be at the beginning/end of the string, messing with your `strpos()` function

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked for me.

```
<?php
 $word = "achievement";
 $word_to_compare = "achiev";
 if(strpos($word,$word_to_compare)!==false){
   echo"Match found";
 }
?>
```

What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Var_dump solved the issue. There was a additional whitespace in one of the variables causing the issue. Using trim helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (strpos($word, $word_to_compare) !== false) 
    echo 'Match Found';
else
    echo 'Match Not Found';
```

This should work perfectly!!!

In your case:

```
$word = "achievement";
$word_to_compare = "achiev";

if(strpos($word, $word_to_compare) !== false)
{
    echo "Match found";
}
```

This returns "Match found" as Result... Please write the code perfectly, it should work...

And, thanks for giving negative point :)